# Pig flatten and group all

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have two  files and I want to do the union of these files to produce a single file as output.

```
file1 = "Hello world"
file2 = "I am x";
c = union file1,file2;
group = group c all;
group = (all,{(Hello world),(I am x)});
```

I want the output as (Hello world I am x);

How to achieve it? I have tried:

```
res = foreach group generate flatten(all);
```

But it's not working..

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
x = load 'pigin1.txt' as (str1:chararray);

y = load 'pigin.txt' as (str2:chararray);

z = rank x;

z1 = rank y;

z2 = join z by rank_x,z1 by rank_y;

z3 = foreach z2 generate  CONCAT(z::str1,z1::str2);

dump z3;
```